# What good and up to date Facebook API tutorials are available?

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

I invested quite some time searching for good and up to date tutorials on using the Facebook API. I can't seem to find anything. Even the Facebook developer documentation doesn't contain good examples.

What good tutorials are available? I'm particularly interested in creating feed posts via the Facebook API.

Comment: Which SDK are you planning to use for that? (js, php, something else?)

Comment: Probably JavaScript, PHP, and/or FBML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/) at the Facebook dev site  help out a lot. They are some good devs there and a post there about your requirement will be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thoroughly evaluated this, but it looks useful:

- http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/